# set CURL on template blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I want to get image from instagram link. the link is this `https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t`

if you open that link. it will redirect the link into actual image link. The redirect link is this

```
https://scontent-xsp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s150x150/95528722_148590620037203_2029915803294658254_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-xsp1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=jeCE5U4ckBkAX8I42Og&oh=79d2aee23705bd88b58801d877642aed&oe=5F22A9C3
```

that redirect link that i want to capture. and store into DB.

because im using AWS server. i can't get the actual image link from controller. i need to get the link into front end. so i create template blade to get the actual link. i was created file call  `instagram.blade.php` and i create this code :

```
<?php
        $image = "https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        preg_match("|location: (https?://\S+)|", $result, $link);
  
        dump($link[1]);
    ?>
```

this code can run well into my local PC.. but when i tried it into my AWS server. it display this execption

```
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /home/ec2-user/......./views/instagram.blade.php)
```

how do i solve this?

parameter `$link[1]` must return this link

```
https://scontent-xsp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440a/s150x150/95528722_148590620037203_2029915803294658254_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-xsp1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=jeCE5U4ckBkAX8I42Og&oh=79d2aee23705bd88b58801d877642aed&oe=5F22A9C3
```

please help

Comment: Just an FYI: This is in violation of the [Instagram terms of use](https://help.instagram.com/1188470931252371) and they have probably taken a lot of measures to counter it. It's possible they block AWS IPs because they tend to be where automated scripts live.

Comment: but i open it from the template. it should read the User browser IP. not the AWS server. isnt it?

Comment: What you shared is PHP code which runs on the server. Another FYI: Instagram seems to have an [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) which will probably be a better (and more ToS friendly) solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'your header');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode('your fields data'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    } catch(Exeption $e){
        return $e ;
    }

    return $result ;
```

Comment: thank you but that code is for post right? but i want to get the data